# New to github - how to add a file to repository / using command line

Tags: git, github, command, push, fetch

Im just started using github (+using the command line) and am so confused about everything. As I understand I have to

1. create repository
   2.(using command line): Initialize the local directory as a Git repository -->git init
2. git add (name folder or file I want to add to the github repository)
3. git commit -m ""
4. git remote add origin remote repository URL -->the repository I want to add the local file/folder to
5. git remote -v (no idea what thats suppose to do)
6. git push origin master

After the last one - git push origin master what happens is that im being told is:  ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)

1. What is fetch and how to I write it?
2. Is it that I sometimes can JUST push the file and other times I have to FIRST fetch it and then push? Can someone explain why and when?

btw. github seems like the worst on earth!! so many commands for just ONE thing which is to push a file into that repository..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The sequence you described above from 1-6 is the process for creating your **local git repository** and linking to a **remote git repository**. In this case the remote repository would be hosted in **Github**.

Notice that **Github** and **Git** are two different things. **Github** is a company offering remote git repositories and related services (https://github.com/)

Then **Git** is the version control system itself. A DVCS created by Linus Torvalds.

For my experience uploading a fresh repository to Github (or any other provider like Bitbucket) you have to use this command:

```
git push -u origin --all
```

Then the whole repo and its references will be uploaded.

This command `git remote -v` just gives you information about what sort of remotes you have attached to your repository.

Comment: When I try git remote -v it just lists the repository I actually have deleted and never was trying to push anything into that repository -it lists that repositry twice saying fetch and then lists it again saying (push) what does that mean??Thanks!!

Comment: @learningcoding Well, you have a `git push origin master` in that list, so you were positively trying to push something. `git remote -v` just lists the remotes that you have set for your repository. `-v` is for verbose.

Answer (score 0):

For your question below.

You should use  `git pull`, that's command do a `git fetch` and next do the `git merge`.

Also you can use `git push origin master --force`.

If you use a `git push origin master --force` command, you may have problems in the future.

Comment: But why do I have to use the pull and merge command? When do I only use push and when do I have to use pull/merge? Also I keep getting : remote origin already exists -what does it mean?Also I had several repositories just for testing purposes and now I deleted some and am trying to push a file into one part. repository (Im naming it) but the file is somehow still being pushed into the old deleted repository-why?Thanks

Comment: When your codes change on your server, you must use `git pull`. Because if you not use them, there will be conflict.

`git push` : when your code changes on your local computer and it's will sent to servers. For getting: remote origin already exists, because your remote it's already on your projects, to change them use `git remote rm origin` or with git configuration `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/projectname.git` . Pushing on your repository would be like this. `git add -u; git add .` them `git commit -am 'message'`. finnale you can push `git push`

Comment: "When your codes change on your server" I had a repository on github with only 1 file- read, then I tried to push a new file into that repository-NOT change the realm file and push it?!  "because your remote it's already on your projects" meaning that the my local repository became a git repository so even if I don't change a file (in existing in my git repository) and just want to add a new file to it, I can't add the new file with the commands I used when I pushed the FIRST file into the repository?! Sorry, Im really new to all this, also new to command lines etc.

Comment: Just use command `git pull`, and your file on github will be downloaded to your local computer. `pull` like download and `push` like upload. all of them you can learn here  https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 . you new on command lines? seriously?

Comment: but i don't want any file to be downloaded from github- instead I am trying to add a local file TO the github repository - lol and yes I am new to command lines-why is that so surprising?Im not a coder

Comment: Yes, you must do that, that's how VCS work.
Hahaha, yeah, that surpising to me. What's your job now?

Comment: Don't really get what you mean- why am I supposed to download a file FROM github if I JUST WANT to 'upload' a file TO github-what am I suppose to download?? hmm do you think everyone knows and uses command lines-If you're not a developer?